# android back button handling

Tags: android

I currently have a project in which the main activity launches another activity for information gathering and then goes back to the main activity. I am trying to handle the back button press. Every time I execute the following code it crashes. But I don't understand why.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
};
```

I have also tried:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            finish();
    };
```

Stack trace:

```
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {peaBerry.Shopping.Consultant/peaBerry.Shopping.Consultant.PeaBerryTeaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2655)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2697)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:124)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at peaBerry.Shopping.Consultant.PeaBerryTeaActivity.onActivityResult(PeaBerryTeaActivity.java:312)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3958)
09-14 15:30:13.740: E/AndroidRuntime(32400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2651)
```

Comment: this code is in my second activity that is launched from the main activity. clarification

Comment: Why don't you use onBackPressed()?

Comment: "It breaks"? How? Does it crash? Does it do nothing? Does your computer disintegrate?

Comment: because that also makes my app crash.

Comment: Please post the stack trace (eclipse, logcat tab, lots of red text)

Comment: Do you need back button handling at all - by default pressing back button finishes current Activity and moves to previous Activity in Activity stack.

Comment: the reason I want back button handling is because I initially didn't have it and my application would crash when i would press the button

Comment: Are you using onActiviyResult in the Activity that you're going back to? It looks like that may be causing the crash

Comment: You shouldnt have to handle back button. The fact it was crashing when you pressed back is another issue. Overriding it to do the same thing is pointless.

Comment: @Orthmius I think your problem is there - not in your onBackPressed

Comment: @doomsknight
what would be my next step then to try and trace down why it was crashing when it should have handled it by default?

Comment: that was it guys... I was expecting something everytime in my onActivityResult() in the main activity. I have since added handling for when 'data' is null and it works out perfectly. I feel I need to learn the logcat/stack trace better. Does anyone have any helpful sites or tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, a result is missing. Have you started the 2nd Activity with `startActivityForResult()`? If so, add a [setResult(value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) or [setResult(value, data)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) before calling `finish()` in your 2nd Activity, to pass back the expected result to the calling Activity.